# CSS Fonts not working ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I use @font-face in my .css styles sheet and it works fine for chrome an mozilla but ie wont load the font the only way i can get ie to load the font is to include the @font-face in the header of every page.

Can anyone tell me why ie will only load it if i include the font, in the header an not in the styles sheet?

```
/*-------------------------FONTS------------------------------*/
@font-face {
 font-family: Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed;
 src: url("/graphic_include/css/Font/Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}

@font-face {
 font-family: Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed;
 src: url("/graphic_include/css/Font/Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

Comment: Apparently, its good to have a direct URL to the `.eot` unless its in the same folder as the `.css` file. Also recommend you give this thread a once over to see if it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753838/internet-explorer-font-face-is-failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve it would be if google had it in its database.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tw+Cen+MT+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Or.. Find a similar font in google's database.

**EDIT**

[Here is google's FONT database](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect)