# EOT font doesn't work in Internet Explorer when website is online (works fine when offline)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, eot

I used the following code to embed the fonts in my website. This font works fine online and offline in Chrome and Firefox. But it doesn't appear in Internet Explorer when I upload the site.

Is there any setting that I'm supposed to do on my hosting site or is there any specific settings regarding character set?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

<style type="text/css"> 
@font-face
{
font-family:GothamBook;
src:url('fonts/gothambook.eot');
src:url('fonts/gothambook.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/gothambook.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/gothambook.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/gothambook.svg#svg/gothambook') format('svg')

}
</style>
</head>
```

please help me i want to make this code work in Internet explorer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753838/internet-explorer-font-face-is-failing

Comment: @MikeSpy No, this is definitely a different problem. The syntax looks ok, I think problem might be in Apache config.

Comment: I didn't say that it is a duplicate. I just wanted you to try the font squirrel: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: @MikeSpy You are leading the wrong way. This syntax is known as ["the new booletproof"](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax), I believe Font Squirell uses the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
```

to your .htaccess file

Comment: i don't know where .htaccess file is located and how to configure it..can you please help me to find it or if i need to create it than how can i create it.? i hope the solution you gave may work..because i checked out the synatax and other thigs everything is fine and the site fonts gets embedded in chrome , and safari and other browser but i am getting problem with IE only that the fonts are not working and i am also having problem with layout , that elements in the page move slit from its original place.

Comment: It should be located in the www root folder on the server if you are running on apache.If you are running MS add it to your webconfig.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a cross-site access issue that requires settings in the server hosting the fonts: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header` needs to be set to allow access from a different domain. See [How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header).