# Text cross browser issue

Tags: css, text

I have begun creating a new website and this time I really want to make sure I get cross-browser issues dealt with because I see this as being extremely important for my own development skills.

In both Chrome & Firefox, the text I have styled appears as I would expect it to style. This is not the case in IE. In fact what appears in IE is not too different to the font I am writing in here.

Below is the code in my css..

```
h.title{
font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", Charcoal, "Helvetica Inserat", "Bitstream Vera Sans Bold", "Arial Black", sans serif;
color:#060;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Below is html

```
 <h class="title">Contact</h>
```

View in Chrome and Firefox..

[image: view in chrome]

View in IE

[image: view in IE]

Any help/explanations would be appreciated many thanks.

Comment: Do you mind sharing at least a screenshot so that we know what problem you are seeing?

Comment: Is it a typo in your question? There's actually no HTML element `<h>`. So `h.title` shouldn't do anything.

Comment: Just updated the post as you probably have seen, images and html added

Answer (score 0):

Many of the fonts you are trying to use in IE may not be supported by IE. Use @font-face (Google will give you links to loads of tutorials), and read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753838/internet-explorer-font-face-is-failing) for good advice and tools for using web fonts with IE.