# HTML - Fonts will only display correct in Chrome but not in IE or Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have created a new page on my company website. It looks awesome but only in Google Chrome.

The fonts do not display correctly within Internet explorer nor Firefox.

Here is the link to the page. (the actual content is inside an iframe which is http://www.lynch.ie/test/map.html)

http://www.lynch.ie/test/test.html

**Thanks,**

Please help me, im on my knees with this one! Thank you in advance.

David L.

Comment: Useful links: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html

Comment: I get a `CSS3117` error several times when viewing your site using IE 10! Please take a look at the dev console (`F12`).

Comment: Thanks guys ill read over all of this and see what I can come up with. Appreciate both your time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're loading the font files from a different domain.

Firefox and possibly IE do not allow that unless you set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, sample (credits to [Callum Silcock's blog article](https://coderwall.com/p/v4uwyq)):

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: that's true, ive tried adding them locally to http://www.lynch.ie/test/fonts/ and updating the .css file but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @DavidLynch I changed the `font-family` property (using dev console) to `"GothamLight","Wingdings"` and IE shows me the Wingdings font. The first font cannot be loaded somehow.

Comment: @DavidLynch Try putting the EOT file as the last source (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14506177/603003)). Is the problem solved because you accepted my answer?

Comment: ill try using google fonts maybe and load them in the html directly and see how that works out... many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey again, I hit the accept because I liked your reply. Didn't know it meant that I accepted your answer as a fix. Im new sorry about that.

Comment: I will read that post over now and see what I can come up with. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidLynch I would set up a simple test file on your server with only minimal HTML and CSS. Try if IE can load the font on that site. (Accepting means that my post has solved/answered your question/problem.)