# my added font-face font does not show in ie

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem with my font,i have used font-face in my `css` code
this font work correctly in my ie browser bu my head bar
[image]

**but when i change font to english everything work correctly as you can see below**

[image]
**as i said that font work correctly in other part of my website**
my css code is below

```css
margin-right:15px;
color:white;
background-color:#75b925;
border:1px solid #649a24;
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-180deg, #83CD2B 0%, #7EC826 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(-180deg, #83CD2B 0%, #7EC826 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-180deg, #83CD2B 0%, #7EC826 100%);
box-shadow: -1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),inset 0px -2px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),inset 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
-moz-transition:box-shadow 0.3s;
-o-transition:box-shadow 0.3s;
 font-family:fanwood,tabassom;
-webkit--transition:box-shadow 0.3s;
-webkit-text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
padding:6px;
font-size:17px;
border-radius:10px;
```

**i have changed many font related settings like `font-weight` `font-size` etc but nothing changed**

```css
@font-face{
    font-family:"tabassom";
    src:url("/fonts/farsi/BTabassom.eot?#") format("eot"),  
          url("/fonts/farsi/BTabassom.woff") format("woff"),
          url("/fonts/farsi/BTabassom.ttf") format("truetype"); 
}
```

Comment: The CSS you provided is not the part we need to see. Show us how you're calling the font.

Comment: thank your your comment i added...as i said this problem is just in my head bar

Comment: Try to specify the character encoding for the HTML document. add <meta charset="UTF-8"> to html header.

Comment: i added but nothing changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer @font-face is failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753838/internet-explorer-font-face-is-failing)

Comment: See if the second answer there works.

Comment: i do not think because as i said this issue is only in my head bar not all over my website

Comment: You said "when I change the font to English everything works correctly" what do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean english language fonts like impact font...becaus i use resource file to have two language in my site

Comment: i just noticed when i set font-weight to 100 just a little part of words is appeared but not completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just set `display:inline-block` and everything got rounded...!