# Why is a .eot web font not being downloaded from a Tomcat server to IE 11?

Tags: oauth, internet-explorer-11, cas, webfonts

We have a CAS OAuth running on Tomcat. Upon initial load in the browser, our web font don't display in IE 11. IE's dev tools network panel shows that IE gets a http status 200 for the font, but it doesn't fully download the font. When another request-response to OAuth is made (e.g., failed or successful authentication) the web font downloads and displays correctly. Any clues out there? Thanks

Comment: Please check your code, whether it works well on other browser, such as Chrome and Edge. If still meet this issue, you might need to check your code. If it works well on other browsers, first, open the IE browser Internet Options and check whether it enable font downloads (in the security zones). Besides, I suggest you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753838/internet-explorer-font-face-is-failing) to check your code.

Comment: Thanks Zhi. Actually the fonts download and display in IE, just not on the first visit to the sign-in screen. When we look at IE's dev inspector network panel, we can see that IE initiated calls to the font files and also received http status 200 from our web server, but the font files don't fully download - something is stopping them. It's like we get the http headers for the font file but not the actual file.

Comment: Try to refer [this link](http://fontpro.com/abel-font-16098) to create a sample to verify whether the code works well in your IE browser. If it works well, perhaps the issue is related to the server side, if it's still not working, perhaps the issue is related to the IE browser, you could try to resetting the IE browser.